# Could the cluster set of a rational sequence be of intermediate cardinality (given not-CH)?

Tags: set-theory

It's easy to construct a sequence of rational numbers whose set of cluster (or accumulation or limit) points is of any finite cardinality, or is countably infinite, or has the cardinality of the continuum. Thus there appears no obvious barrier to forming a rational sequence with a cluster set of any cardinality up to $\mathfrak{c}$. Now suppose that we reject the continuum hypothesis. Is it consistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$ that there could be an oracular sequence $(a_0 , a_1 , \dots ) \in \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that the cluster set of the sequence $(n_{2i - 1}/n_{2i} : i = 1, 2, \dots)$, where $n_0$ , $n_1$ , ... are the elements of $\{n \in \mathbb{N} : a_n = 1\}$ in natural order, has cardinality strictly between $\omega$ and $\mathfrak{c}$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, closed sets cannot have intermediate cardinality.   One way to see this:  suppose a 
closed subset $K$ of the Cantor set $C$ has greater than countable cardinality. 
It's easy to see that there must be a partition into two open and closed subsets such that
each one has greater than countably many elements of $K$, otherwise you could express
$K$ as a countable union of countable sets.  Likewise, each of these has at a partition
into two closed and open sets with more than countably many elements.  Continuing by
induction and taking the limit, you
get a homeomorphic image of a Cantor set contained in $K$.

Comment: Indeed, the result is due to Cantor himself, who had the strategy of attempting to prove CH by establishing such claims for increasingly complicated sets beyond the closed sets. Although it is consistent with ZFC that there are $\Delta^1_2$ sets of intermediate cardinality, Cantor's original strategy is redeemed by sufficiently large large cardinals, which imply that there can be no projective set that is a counterexample to CH.

Comment: An addendum to Joel's comment: The strategy he mentioned succeeds for  Borel sets (and slightly farther, `$\Sigma^1_1$` sets) even in the absence of large cardinals.  ZFC suffices to prove that all uncountable `$\Sigma^1_1$` sets have perfect subsets and therefore have the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @Joel, @Andreas: Thanks for the information. I was tempted to say that Borel sets can't have intermediate cardinality, but being such a non-expert I wasn't sure. Is it easy to define $\Delta^1_2$ sets, projective sets and $\Sigma^1_1$ sets? If I once knew the definitions, I don't remember them, and these terms aren't so easy to get from google.

Comment: Feeble google: Delta One products are a class of financial derivative that have no optionality and as such have a delta of one (or very close to one) 

Comment: For Borel sets there is a nice "modern" argument, first noting that the result holds for closed sets in any Polish space, and then realizing that for any Borel set $A$, one can change the topology slightly so that a Polish space remains Polishable, the collection of Borel sets does not change, and $A$ becomes open.

Comment: @Bill Thurston: $\Sigma^1_1$ sets are the continuous images of Borel sets. Their complements are $\Pi^1_1$. Their continuous images are $\Sigma^1_2$. Their complements are $\Pi^1_2$, etc. A $\Delta^1_n$ set is one that is simultaneously $\Pi^1_n$ and $\Sigma^1_n$. All these sets are collectively called projective. (Suslin showed that $\Delta^1_1$ coincides with Borel.) Of course, although Joel will disagree, there are no projective sets of intermediate size, and that ZFC does not suffice to prove this simply shows that ZFC is almost but not quite the right formalization of set theory.

Comment: Bill, the $\Sigma^1_1$ sets are also known as the analytic
sets, the projections of Borel sets from a higher dimension
(or equivalently, continuous images). The $\Delta^1_2$ sets
are simultaneously the projection of an analytic set and of
the complement of an analytic set. The projective sets
arise from the Borel sets by closing under projections and
complements. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy


Comment: Sorry, I should have said that the $\Delta^1_2$ sets are simultaneously the projection of a co-analytic set (i.e. $\Sigma^1_2$), and the complement of such a set (so also $\Pi^1_2$). A key aspect of this level of complexity is that in G&ouml;del's constructible universe $L$, and elsewhere, there is a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ of complexity $\Delta^1_2$. This is why it is consistent with ZFC that various bad behavior can occur at the level of $\Delta^1_2$, such as non-measurable sets, or sets of intermediate cardinality (in a forcing extension of $L$). 

Comment: @Bill Thurston: Thank you for your definitive answer. Thanks also to Joel and the others who went beyond my naive question to tackle the more significant one of where in the projective hierarchy the possibility of intermediate cardinality first arises ($\Delta^1_2$ sets). If I understand correctly, there are two interpretations of this: (1) Intermediacy shouldn't arise at such low complexity, and its appearance points to the inadequacy of the present axioms (ZFC) of mathematics; and (2) independence phenomena will always be with us---just happening to be at $\Delta^1_2$ in this case.